# DocStream, DocToStream compile lines into a file

Tags: 2013, content-database

In SharePoint 2013 Ent to database **WSS_Content** there are tables **DocStream** and **DocToStream**, they store information about the file in the form of binary data. I noticed that in SP 2013 the file is stored as several lines, i.e. file is divided into several lines, tell me, is there a mechanism how to assemble these lines into a normal working file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the logic to do so is in SharePoint's own code. There are no 3rd party tools that assemble shredded storage documents.

Comment: Thanks Travor, but is VEEAM SharePoint tools by some logic it collects?

Comment: Veeam will backup the database and use SharePoint APIs to restore individual documents. That's significantly different from attempting to stitch together the binary streams from the database itself.